# Why is my perl Catalyst redirect_and_detach replacement plugin method failing?

Tags: perl, plugins, catalyst

Looking for help figuring out a stumping error.

I've created a perl Catalyst plugin that's intended to provide a drop-in replacement method for Catalyst 5.90115's redirect_and_detach ($c->redirect_and_detach).  My replacement method does nothing but call Catalyst's redirect_and_detach:

```
package MyApp::Catalyst::Plugin::Logger;
...

sub my_redirect_and_detach {
  my ($c, $uri, $status) = @_;

  $c->redirect_and_detach($uri, $status);
}
```

I realize this adds no value, I'm just testing to make this simple case work first.

Then I replace this working call ...

```
$c->redirect_and_detach($someuri);
```

with this call to my new plugin method ...

```
$c->my_redirect_and_detach($someuri);
```

And I get the following (abbreviated/obfuscated) error:

```
Parameter #2 (undef) to Catalyst::Plugin::RedirectAndDetach::redirect_and_detach was an 'undef', which is not one of the allowed types: scalar
 at /usr/local/share/perl/5.26.1/Catalyst/Plugin/RedirectAndDetach.pm line 18.
    Catalyst::Plugin::RedirectAndDetach::redirect_and_detach(undef, "/myuri", undef) called at /var/app/lib/MyApp/Catalyst/Plugin/Logger.pm line 95
    MyApp::Catalyst::Plugin::Logger::my_redirect_and_detach(MyApp=HASH(0x5628f93e4e60), "/myuri") called at ...
```

I understand the Catalyst method spec requires parameter #2 to be defined.  But I don't understand why the stacktrace shows undef for the first argument (thought that would be $c's class/package).  I verified $c is successfully passed as first argument, and works inside my_redirect_and_detatch() to pull request parameters.

Anyone see the issue?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out Catalyst's redirect_and_attach(), while $status defaults to undef if not supplied, does not like an actual undef $status parameter.  Solution is to avoid passing $status if it's undef.